# Enc28j60 with Arduino hang when using with Android mobile

Tags: arduino

I am using [Enc28j60](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en022889) with Arduino Uno and make LED control via web. It works fine when I am using with my computer web browser but  when I am using my Android phone for control then this will hang and doesn't give any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer consists of two parts:

1)  You need to provide more information, what hangs?  the phone or the arduino?  Also, what debugging things have you done.

2)  To help with debugging, you need to "see" the network traffic between the arduino and the phone.  Can you modify the Arduino to print out the traffic it receives.  Specifically, you need to display the GET HTTP header.

The network header traffic is ascii text, you can print the traffic back to your IDE.

The theory of this problem is that the phone is sending data in the HTTP header that is **not** handled correctly by the Arduino and it causes the A. to continuously loop.

A header contains, besides the "GET HTTP..." text, also entity pairs like "keyword: value"
and the phone is probably sending a pair that drives a bug in the Arduino.

Finally, since the web page works from a "normal" then for now we can assume that the page itself is NOT the problem, but that the transport is, thus the phone is probably sending unexpected header info.

Comment: My Arduino is hangs, it may work some time for 1,2 click but after that it will hang.

Comment: @Ramoliya.Biren, that is indicative that there is a bug in the Arduino's TCP/IP stack.  Essentially, you will have to go into the ENC28J60 code and modify it with debugging statements.  As a first step, get the ENC28J60 code to Serial.print the data back into the Arduino IDE.  This way you can see on what traffic the Ard. hangs.

Comment: @Ramoliya.Biren, can I ask what the specific problem was.  I have an ENC28J60 myself, so I am curious...?